# json.net and incremental processing of the twitter streaming API

Tags: c#, json, twitter, json.net

I'm trying to make use of the Twitter streaming API in an incremental fashion to process root objects one by one and return each one via a callback asynchronously. I've seen implementations counting the number of { vs } and waiting for the numbers to balance at 0 then processing that chunk of data although to me this really just didn't feel safe.

My plan was to make use of a json.net JsonTextReader and use TokenType and Depth to do this job. This is working well in that it is a very reliable way of splitting the read at the end of each object, I just cannot figure out how to get that data into the Deserialize method. The Deserialize method does accept a JsonTextReader as an argument but that processes from that point onwards (it's a forward only stream after all) so I'm stuck. There is also a DeserializeObjectAsync method available but that only accepts a string.

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if (jsonReader.Depth == 0 && jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
            {

                //newTweetCallback(jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Tweet>([Some magic here. Help!]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious as a result of staring at the particular application for too long.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, instead of handling the depth yourself, you can pass the partially used JsonTextReader to Deserialize, which will not read further than to the end token:

```
while (jsonReader.Read())
{
    if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        newTweetCallback(jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Tweet>(jsonReader));
        // Debug.Assert(jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject);
    }
}
```

So there's no need to read ahead yourself.